# Is `webdriver-manager start` necessary?

Tags: angularjs, selenium, webdriver-manager

I'm delving into the world of Protractor tests for AngularJS.

All the tutorials recommend I execute the following after `webdriver-manager update` and prior to executing the test:

`webdriver-manager start`

According to the `webdriver-manager` man, the `start` command will 'start up the selenium server'. True enough, once I run the above command, I can see something at http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub

**My questions is: is the above necessary?**

I currently run my tests without the above command.

All I do is:

`webdriver-manager update
php -S localhost:8000 -t dist/
protractor ./test/protractor.config.js`

My tests run as expected even though I've excluded `webdriver-manager start`.

Can someone please explain why `webdriver-manager start` is necessary?

:EDIT:

My **protractor/fooTests.js**:

```
exports.config = {
    directConnect: true,
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome'
    },
    specs: ['protractor/fooTests.js'],
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
    }
};
```

My **protractor/fooTests.js**:

```
describe('test for the bar code', function() {
    it('should login', function() {
        browser.get('http://localhost:8000');

        element(by.model('password')).sendKeys('123456');
        element(by.css('[type="submit"]')).click();
    });
    it('should inspect element ', function() {
        expect(element(by.id('foo-script')).isPresent()).toBe(true);
        console.log('Login Success');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Protractor is sending commands to Selenium and Selenium is communicating with the browsers using its drivers.

```
webdriver-manager start
```

is starting Selenium.

There are 3 basic options:

1. `directConnect`. That makes protractor communicate with the selenium drivers directly, without using the Selenium server. However, the functionality of this option is limited:

> directConnect: true - Your test script communicates directly Chrome Driver or Firefox Driver, bypassing any Selenium Server. If this is true, settings for seleniumAddress and seleniumServerJar will be ignored. If you attempt to use a browser other than Chrome or Firefox an error will be thrown.

2. Connecting to an already running selenium server (either local or remote), specified by `seleniumAddress`. A server can be started using the `webdriver-manager start` script.
3. Starting the server from the test script.

You can explore all the options in the documentation https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/server-setup.md

Comment: I don't believe Selenium is running, by default.
`ps aux | grep -i selenium` doesn't yield anything. Should I be grepping for something else?

Comment: @Housni grep for Java

Comment: Tried that too, nothing. I do see results when I run `webdriver-manager start` and then grep for it but not otherwise which leads me to believe that Selenium is not running in the background.

Is it possible that the command `protractor ./test/protractor.config.js` is triggering Selenium to run with it?

Comment: @Housni It shouldn't do that, they are completely separate components. Another possibility is that your tests are empty or you are using selenium on another computer? How is your `seleniumAddress` set in config?

Comment: I added the config and my test file to my original post. `seleniumAddress` isn't set.

Comment: @Housni That `directConnect` option makes the problem clear :) Updated the answer.

Comment: I just removed `directConnect` and ran the test without `webdriver-manager start` and it ran fine. However, the output showed that the `protractor ./test/protractor.config.js` ran Selenium as a standalone:
`Starting selenium standalone server...    
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver    
Selenium standalone server started at http://192.168.1.2:55312/wd/hub    
.Login Success    
.    
    
Finished in 16.923 seconds    
2 tests, 1 assertion, 0 failures`

So it seems like, if Selenium is not running, it will be invoked when a test is run. Is that right?

Comment: @Housni Obviously you are right. There are options I never knew were there. I linked the documentation which contains an explanation for all the options.