# Do we really need to run webdriver-manager start before running protractor?

Tags: protractor

In order to run my unit tests against IE, I just run protractor without running the webdriver-manager start. According to the existing online docs (such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30395011/is-webdriver-manager-start-necessary)), we should run selenium server before running tests on browsers except Chrome and Firefox,
Do you know how my does protractor work which doesn't need the selenium server?

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to run the protractor. As you know, first one is to provide the webdriver url in confg.js like `seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'`

In this case, you need to start the webdriver manually by using `webdriver-manager start`

If you do not provide this parameter in your confg.js then protractor will try to invoke webdriver instance on its own. But for the same, you need to have webdriver installed. And that is the second way.

`npm install -g webdriver-manager`

But by default when you install the protractor by using `npm install -g protractor`, `protractor` and `webdriver-manager` both are installed together.

Answer (score 2):

According to the protractor [github page](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4446), protractor will start a selenium server by default. As long as you've webdriver-manager updated, you don't need to run webdriver-manager start.